# Android saving an ArrayList<Object> as SharedPreference

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm currently trying to save an ArrayList containing POJOs as a SharedPreference to retrieve it when the user re-enters the application, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is what I do:

callback methods

```
ArrayList<myObject> myList;
ArrayList<Boolean> myobject_repeat;
MyListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myview);
    lw = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lw);
    myList= new ArrayList<myObject>();
    myobject_repeat = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, myList);
    lw.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    saveArray();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    loadArray(this);
    super.onResume();
}
```

Methods to save/load array

```
public boolean saveArray() {
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
    edit.putInt("list_size", myList.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
        edit.remove("id" + i);
        edit.remove("repeat" + i);
        edit.putLong("id" + i, myList.get(i).getId());
        edit.putBoolean("repeat" + i, myList.get(i).isRepeat());
    }

    return edit.commit();
}

public void loadArray(Context c) {
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
    myList.clear();
    myList2.clear();
    int listsize = pref.getInt("list_size", 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < listsize; i++) {
        MyObject tmpObject = new MyObject();
        tmpObject.setId(pref.getLong("id" + i, 0));
        tmpObject.setRepeat(pref.getBoolean("repeat" + i, false));
        myList.add(tmpObject);
    }

}
```

This is where I add an object to the array

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent result) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, result);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        int hour = result.getExtras().getInt("hour");
        int minute = result.getExtras().getInt("minute");
        boolean repeat = result.getExtras().getBoolean("repeat");
        setUpObject(hour, minute, repeat);
    }
}

private void setUpObject(int hour, int minute, boolean repeat) {

    //Doing magic tricks

    MyObject tmpObject= new MyObject ();
    tmpObject.setHours(hour);
    tmpObject.setMinutes(minute);
    tmpObject.setRepeat(repeat);
    tmpObject.setId(timeInMs);

    myList.add(tmpObject);
    adapter.remove(tmpObject);
    adapter.add(tmpObject);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This does not seem to work. When I debug it the lists are empty. If I run the app without the load/save methods it works as intended but as you can see, the lists wont be persisted in SharedPreferences and therefore not available when the user navigates back to my activity.

Any help here is really appreciated.

Marcus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem here: onPause was called after onActivityResult which overwrite my array with an empty array.

Comment: Oh , I didn't use onActivityResult to fill out the data, that was tricky :)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts tho

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [GSON library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

You can convert your `ArrayList` to string and store to Preference and when you get back convert that string to same ArrayList.

```
   //-- code to convert list to string using Gson
     Type listType = new TypeToken<List<myObject>>() {}.getType();
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     String json = gson.toJson(target, listType);
    // store this string to shared preference


    //-- code to convert this string to list
    String json = gson.toJson(target, listType);
    List<String> target2 = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
```

Comment: I really want to solve this without using an external library, but thanks for your answer anyway

Comment: it is jar file u just have to put into lib folder.

Comment: Do you have a link? my searches only returns deprecated version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62004/discussion-between-marcus-and-jatin).

Comment: I'm giving up for today but will try again tomorrow. Can you add me on skype?  Marcussjaconsson

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you add **tmpAlarm** in the line :

*myList.add(tmpAlarm);*

it should be

*myList.add(tmpObject);*

```
public void loadArray(Context c) {
  SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
  myList.clear();
  myList2.clear();
  int listsize = pref.getInt("list_size", 0);

  for (int i = 0; i < listsize; i++) {
    MyObject tmpObject = new MyObject();
    tmpObject.setId(pref.getLong("id" + i, 0));
    tmpObject.setRepeat(pref.getBoolean("repeat" + i, false));
    myList.add(tmpAlarm);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thats very wierd. When I run it it doesn't even loop

Comment: @Marcus I say that the code works fine, because I checked it in an app. You can do something else, just print in the console what you save and what you load. I have done the same and works.

Comment: Its very wierd that it worked for you. Look at my answer, that was the issue